# If I make the table of contentsr and in a frame I have an itemize that is going on many frames, in the table of contents will be all the frames

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, itemize

Beamer
So, this is my code:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Cuprins}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

And in the first frame I have a itemize which goes on more than 1 frame:

```
        \section{name}
        \frametitle{name}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> text
            \item<2-> text
                \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

So the text from item 1 is on a frame, and the text from item 2 is on another frame.
So my table of contents is like this:

**1. name
2. name
....**

I want "name" to appear just one time. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SE! The code prints 'name' just once for me. Do you have more code around this?